# How to manually mark lines and store to register

Tags: vim

What is an easy way to manually mark arbitrary lines and yank/delete them without writing to the document?

Eg line 10,17,33 in a 50 line document. Without using the line numbers, though.

My workaround so far:

I put a unique string at the beginning of the lines, eg x and

```
:g/^x/y R
```

yank them to a register (r in this case)

After putting I still have to delete the string

```
:s/^x//g
```

How can this be done better and without temporarily changing the document?

EDIT:

I want to keep the advantages of this method:

- Keep the original order regardless of the order I marked the lines
- I can see which lines are marked already

The fewer keystrokes per line the better, of course

Answer (score 1):

If it's no more than 26 locations in the buffer, I would mark them with lowercase marks (`ma`, `mb`, ...), then step through them from the beginning of the buffer with `]'` while yanking them into an uppercase register:

```
gg]'"ryy]'"Ryy]'"Ryy...
```

Unfortunately, `]'` doesn't beep when there's no more mark, so you cannot employ a recursive macro that would automatically stop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor to the first line, do `"Ryy`, repeat.